# Using SVN post-commit to update a .txt file

Tags: svn, post-commit, svnlook

First of all, i am on Windows 7, if that makes a difference, using Cygwin.
I'am using a dropbox as my svn repo, where i can manage multiple projects. After each commit to each projects, i want to update a file `changelog.txt` in `public_root` folder, and if it's possible, commit the changes made after post-commit script.

`post-commit` file located under `/hooks` folder in svn repo:

```
#!/bin/sh

REPOS=$1
REV=$2

/usr/bin/svnlook info $REPOS >> $REPOS/changelog.txt
```

Actually it place a `changelog.txt` into svn repo folder, what i want is to put it inside the folder of my checked out project (sorry for not knowing the right terms to describe)

Any advice ?

Comment: are you looking for something like this http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2006-08/0825.shtml

Comment: oh man i love you! so lame from me to not check it out on official blog post

Comment: Current svn2log [home](http://core.com.pl/svn2log/) changed

Comment: yes, i found it on http://core.com.pl/svn2log/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$REPOS` refers to the location of the whole repository and not a checked out copy. The Subversion server cannot possibly know where the client is going to write the data.

It is also not possible to modify the repository itself upon committing (as modifying a file).

If you are the only user of the repository and you always check out the stuff in the same sandbox you can hard-code the location in your post-commit hook

```
/usr/bin/svnlook info $REPOS >> /the/location/of/my/sandbox/changelog.txt
```

Comment: thanks @Matteo for answer, but i prefer to not use hard-coding in anyway.

Comment: @aspirinemaga there is no way for the server to know where the client could check out the data.